# Как поменять текст в телеграме по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

В телеграм канале снизу под постом есть кнопка, нужно при нажатии на нее менять текст на немного другой. Сообщение должно отправляться ботом в канал (с кнопкой), чтобы я в любой момент мог нажать кнопку и он поменялся на нужный (который я указал)

Пример:

[image]

При нажатии на кнопку "Кнопка", текст с надписью "test" должен поменяться на другой (который я укажу). Как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно реализовать, добавив `call_data` кнопке. Дальше её можно отловить через `callback_query_handler` и изменить текст сообщения через `message.edit_text`